# Issue with vertex level editing in ArcScene

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, arcscene, multipatch

I have a 3D data set of some buildings in ESRI Shapefile MultiPatch format. The buildings appear in 3D in ArcScene (10.2.1 on Windows 8.1 64bit) and I am able to move, rotate and scale buildings. However when I select a building in an editing session and I go to vertex editing, if I try to edit any of the vertices of my building I am presented with a 'Select a single editable feature to modify' prompt. I am unable to work out why I can't edit at vertex level for this set of buildings.

[image: A depiction of the error that I'm getting]

In addition clicking on the building appears to make it disappears until I select another building and the original building reappears. Anyone have any thoughts about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcScene does not support vertex level editing for MultiPatch files, however ArcScene does not alert you to this fact. 
[Source](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q8000000qs000000)

Answer (score 1):

@Loxodrome correctly answered that you can't do this in ArcScene. However, the workflow for editing buildings is to export multipatch to collada then open the file and edit in [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/) (free software). Once complete, replace the multipatch in ArcScene with the edited one.

Comment: The tool for this is in Arc and it's called "MultiPatch to Collada" if anyone is wondering!